# Как правильно сформулировать рекламное сообщение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, реклама

**Конфеты этой серии — с шоколадом. Данное предложение будет в продаже в марте.**

Речь идет о конфетах, разве может предложение продаваться?

Comment: Стрела, большая просьба: расширьте свой вопрос, добавив туда Ваш вариант из комментария, чтобы дать знатокам более широкие возможности для ответов и не делать полотно из коммантариев - формат нашего форума несколько иной.  
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В бизнес-лексике слова **"предложение"** и **"позиция"** довольная часто используются для обозначения товара или услуги.
Простейший пример:

> Данная позиция сейчас недоступна, но у нас есть для вас другие похожие предложения

В переводе на "человеческий язык" это означает один из двух вариантов:

> Данный товар сейчас недоступен, но у нас есть для вас другие похожие товары
>   Данная услуга сейчас не может быть оказана, но мы можем предложить вам другие похожие услуги

Хотя лично я бы для рекламного сообщения подобную лексику не применял. Здесь уместнее что-то в стиле:

> Конфеты этой серии - с шоколадом.
>   В продаже - уже в марте!

Comment: Не согласен. "Наше предложение — диван", означает, что мы вам предлагаем диван, из не то, что диван можно подменять словом "предложение". Продается диван, а не предложение.  Позиция — другое дело, это как бы "товар номер такой-то".

Comment: @М_Г, в бизнес-лексике есть такой термин - "коммерческое предложение". В обиходе его очень часто сокращают до одного слова: "предложение". Причем "предложением" может быть тот же диван, если его можно будет приобрести на определенных условиях (например, в определенное время, в определенном месте или по определенной цене). Фразу "наше коммерческое предложение - поставка дивана такой-то модели по такой-то цене и с такими-то доп. условиями", можно повторно использовать в тексте, сократив до "наше предложение", если из ранее сказанного понятно, о каком именно товаре/услуги идет речь.

Comment: Все, что Вы пишете, верно, но никак не доказывает того, что можно писать и говорить о **продаже** предложения.

Comment: @М_Г, я согласен с Вами, что предложение нельзя продать. Но его можно именно **предложить**, точно так же, как можно предложить товар или услугу. Поэтому вполне корректно фразу *"этого дивана сейчас нет, но мы можем предложить другой диван"* заменить на **"этого дивана сейчас нет, но у нас есть для вас другое предложение"**. По крайней мере, на практике подобные замены используются довольно часто.

Comment: Нет возражений.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

- Данный товар будет доступен начиная с марта.
- Данный товар поступит в продажу в марте.
- Этот товар будет в продаже в марте.
- Этот товар начнет продаваться в марте.

Это все довольно формальные, официальные варианты. Для рекламного объявления подошло бы что-нибудь покороче:

Конфеты этой серии -- с шоколадом. В продаже с марта.

Правда, это какая-то старомодная реклама получается. По-современному -- в основном тексте поставить звездочку/нумерованную сноску, а про март написать мелкими буквами примечание.